# Use wildcard output as a variable in an arithmetic computation

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, files, rename

I have files with names and directory paths as follows:

> t10n2/data/file.dat0, t10n2/data/file.dat1, t10n2/data/file.dat2, ...

I wish to change the names of the files using an arithmetic operation which involves the variables `$1` and `$2` in `t10n$1` and `dat$2`, such that the file names are changed to `file.dat$(($1*5 + $2))`.

In particular, I guess what I want to know is how to use the output of a wildcard like `!` or `*` as a variable in an arithmetic operation? The rest I can do.

Comment: the basic command are `find`, `mv` etc.

Comment: I had not asked the write question. I just edited it.

Comment: Achievement unlocked: homework automation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl `rename`:

```
prename -n 's!t10n(\d+)/data/file.dat\K(\d+)!$1*5+$2!e' t10n*/data/file.dat*
```

Remove `-n` when you're happy with the result.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the -n does? And are there no non-Perl alternatives? I am just not used to the syntax.

Comment: `-n` means "dry run". Yes, there are two widespread non-Perl implementations of `rename`.  The Perl one comes from `Unicode::Tussle`.

Answer (score 3):

Using bash:

```
for file in t10*/data/file.dat*
do
  if [[ $file =~ (t10n([[:digit:]]+)/data/file.dat)([[:digit:]]+) ]]
  then
    echo mv -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} * 5 + ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ))"
  fi
done
```

The heavy lifting is done by the `=~` regular-expression operator in the `[[` test operation. There are three parenthesized expressions in order to grab the elements we're interested in:

1. the bulk of the filename, *except for* the trailing `dat` number
2. the `t10n` number
3. the `dat` number

If the file matches the pattern, then the resulting values are in the BASH_REMATCH array, so we use those to calculate the new filename.

Remove the `echo` if the results look correct.

Sample input:

```
mkdir -p t10n2/data t10n3/data
touch t10n2/data/{file.dat0,file.dat1,file.dat2}
touch t10n3/data/{file.dat0,file.dat1,file.dat2}
```

Sample output:

```
mv -- t10n2/data/file.dat0 t10n2/data/file.dat10
mv -- t10n2/data/file.dat1 t10n2/data/file.dat11
mv -- t10n2/data/file.dat2 t10n2/data/file.dat12
mv -- t10n3/data/file.dat0 t10n3/data/file.dat15
mv -- t10n3/data/file.dat1 t10n3/data/file.dat16
mv -- t10n3/data/file.dat2 t10n3/data/file.dat17
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n 't10n(<->)/data/file.dat(<->)' '$f:r.dat$(($1 * 5 + $2))'
```

(remove `-n` (for dry-run) when happy).

Answer (score 0):

**find** + **bash** + **sed** solution:

```
find . -type f -path "*t[0-9]*n[0-9]*/data/file.dat[0-9]*" -exec bash -c 'f=$1; 
      read v1 v2 < <(sed -E "s#.*/t[0-9]+n([0-9]+)/data/file\.dat([0-9]+)\$#\1 \2#" <<<"$f"); 
      mv "$f" "${f/.dat[0-9]*/.dat}$(($v1*5+$v2))"' x {} \;
```

---

- `read v1 v2 ...` - read the crucial numbers from `t10n<number>` and `dat<number>` into `v1` and `v2` variables respectively

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I preferred the other one though, since it was shorter.

Comment: Another way to pass the pathname from find to bash is with command line arguments: `find ... -exec bash -c 'f=$1; ...' x {} \;` -- here "x" will become $0 and the filename gets $1

Comment: Also, the bash manual uses `$((...))` not `$[...]` -- I *think* the latter syntax is deprecated, but I can't find that documented.

Comment: @glennjackman, edited, but I haven't encountered cases when `$[...]` syntax would not work ... yet

Comment: That is true. However, since `$[]` is not documented in the manual, I think it's bad practice to use it in a "teaching" context.